# How to Speed Up Guest OS in Macbook Air 2013-Mid?

Tags: macos, video, virtualbox

I followed the post [here](http://blog.jdpfu.com/2012/09/14/solution-for-slow-ubuntu-in-virtualbox) about *Solution for Slow Ubuntu in VirtualBox*. 
It is not targeted for OS X. 
I am feeling rather slow video play (not native) in the system *Macbook Air 2013-Mid*. 
I feel that some of *default* settings of VB5 may not be appropriate for the system, especially in the video play. 
My settings

[image]

where

- less RAM for guest OS than host OS (2 < 8 GB)
- dynamic space 50 GB so does not end too early
- System > Acceleration > Nested paging On; PAE/NX On; Paravirtualization Default (here, the new VB5 choses KVM automatically);
- System > Processor > 1 CPU (so Host OS has two)
- Display > Memory > 128 GB (can be too much, slowing the system)

### Video play results

Playing just youtube video in Guest OS makes the OS X run in its max where the first process is *VirtualBox VM*

[image]

### USB

I let USB be 1, although the VB5 should support USB3. However, I got a warning after changing the setting to USB2 or USB3 so I left it to be USB1. 
It would however great to get sufficiently configured system.

---

How can you Speed Up Guest OS in Macbook Air 2013-Mid?

Comment: Please keep the text of the question focused on problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @patrix It is focused. VB is not the only choice. Native run is the best case scenario. You need to have some benchmark. VB does badly at the moment.

Comment: "Suggestions for future improvements" doesn't sound like a question somehow.

Comment: @patrix It is body. Question is at the end. Current answers about the topic are very bad. You need to have some benchmark to rate those. Native is the goal. If you cannot measure, you lose.

Comment: There are no answers here at all?! How does the edit you made about running natively make it easier to find answers in any way?